# Mockito when().thenReturn calls the actual method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

This is the method I am trying to test -

```
@Service
public class ShareableLinkService {

    private PaymentService paymentService;

    @Autowired
    public ShareableLinkService(PaymentService paymentService) {  
        this.paymentService = paymentService;
    }

    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> cancelSmartPay(Long id, String merchantRefId) {
        ..
        responseDTO = paymentService.processCancelPayment(id, merchantRefId);
        ..

    }

}
```

And following is the called method -

```
@Service
public class PaymentService {
@Transactional
    public ResponseDTO processCancelPayment(Long param, String merchantRefId) {
    TransactionRequest transactionRequest = transactionRequestService.findByMerchantIdAndMerchantRefId(param, merchantRefId);

..
}
```

Following is my test code -

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SmartPayMockitoServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private PaymentService paymentServiceNew;

    when(paymentServiceNew.processCancelPayment(id,merchantRefId)).thenReturn(new ResponseDTO(Constants.API_RESPONSE_SUCCESS, "transaction cancelled"));

    when(paymentServiceNew.processCancelPayment(id,merchantRefId)).thenReturn(new ResponseDTO(Constants.API_RESPONSE_SUCCESS, "transaction cancelled"));
    assertEquals("1", shareableLinkService.cancelSmartPay(id, merchantRefId).getBody().getStatus().toString());

    assertEquals("1", shareableLinkService.cancelSmartPay(payoutMerchantId, merchantRefId).getBody().getStatus().toString());
```

When I run the cancelSmartPay() call in the last statement, it actually calls the processCancelPayment() method.

I have already checked [Mockito when().thenReturn calls the method unnecessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340007/mockito-when-thenreturn-calls-the-method-unnecessarily)

**Update**

I made it as per @Jalil's answer -

```
@Mock
private PaymentService paymentService;


@InjectMocks
private ShareableLinkService shareableLinkService;
```

However, still, the actual methods are being called. Also, when I am in debug mode, I get a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: You showed us how you instantiate the mock. How do you create service under test?

Comment: @Lesiak added in update

Comment: So far everything looks ok. Difficult to say without seeing entire test.

Comment: You need to make sure that the shareableLinkService object is either 1) a mock object or 2) a spy object with the function cancelSmartPay() that is stubbed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please share how you instantiate the shareableLinkService object.

It should be something like this

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SmartPayMockitoServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private PaymentService paymentServiceNew;

    @InjectMocks
    private ShareableLinkService shareableLinkService;

    // the rest of the code

}
```

Your test should be inside a method annotated with @Test

```
@Test
void testMethod(){

    when(paymentServiceNew.processCancelPayment(id,merchantRefId)).thenReturn(new ResponseDTO(Constants.API_RESPONSE_SUCCESS, "transaction cancelled"));

    when(paymentServiceNew.processCancelPayment(id,merchantRefId)).thenReturn(new ResponseDTO(Constants.API_RESPONSE_SUCCESS, "transaction cancelled"));
    assertEquals("1", shareableLinkService.cancelSmartPay(id, merchantRefId).getBody().getStatus().toString());

    assertEquals("1", shareableLinkService.cancelSmartPay(payoutMerchantId, merchantRefId).getBody().getStatus().toString());

}
```